# ShowBalloonTip-example for Visual Studio 2010 C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to show a ToolTip (BalloonTip) for an existing icon in the notification area of the task bar (sometime called "SystemTray" or "Info Tray").
So there is this method in the MSDN [NotifyIcon::ShowBalloonTip Method (Int32, String, String, ToolTipIcon)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms160065%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1):

```
public:
void ShowBalloonTip(
    int timeout, 
    String^ tipTitle, 
    String^ tipText, 
    ToolTipIcon tipIcon
)
```

> Displays a balloon tip with the specified title, text, and icon in the
>   taskbar for the specified time period.

I think this is exactly what I need, but there is no example for C++ and I don't find any short and clear example in the internet.
Only for C# or VB.NET, but not for VS 2010 C++

Could somebody give me as a VS C++ beginner some short snippet or example how to use this method in the code?

Thank you

frank

Comment: Assuming that you're writing a Windows Forms app in C++/CLI, this could be as simple as calling `MyNotifyIcon->ShowBalloonTip(5000, "Title", "This is a balloon tip.", ToolTipIcon::None);` If you're not writing a Windows Forms app for .NET, then the API doesn't apply to you; you'll need to look at examples like this one: [How to Implement Tooltips for Status Bar Icons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298404(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thank you. But I think I have too few knowledge of Visual Studio C++ as I could understand this. 
I was searching for an example where this BalloonTop already works, a BalloonTip for an existing icon in the notification area of the task bar. I cannot get this code snippets to work, unfortunately, I don't know where to put it that I don't get many errors. Thank you anyway.

Comment: E.g. I put it here:
 HICON icon = 0;
 icon->ShowBalloonTip(5000, "Title", "This is a balloon tip.", ToolTipIcon::None);

will get me an error C2039 'ShowBalloonTip' is not an element of 'HICON__'
and:
error C2653: 'ToolTipIcon': no class or namespace

Comment: You need to give more context to your question, then. You need to say what kind of app you're building (for example, a C++ Win32 app, or a C++/CLI app) and probably what tool set you're using (for example, Visual C++ 2010 Express, Visual Studio 2013 Professional) and maybe even whether you're building a project in the IDE or trying to use the command line tools. It sounds like you're trying to extend an existing app to show a balloon tooltip, but it's hard to explain what to do without knowing a lot more about the project and your coding environment.

Comment: I even don't know the difference between C++ Win32 app or C++/CLI app (is this DotNet?), but I think it is Win32 app. Yes, you are very right, I try to extend an existing app. The name of the application I try to extend is PeerBlock, OpenSource, here ist the code:
http://peerblock.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/peerblock/
My Visual Studio IDE is 2010 Ultimate (test version).

Comment: Now I read about C++/CLI and I think to know that PeerBlock isn't, it is a Win32 app.

I found meanwhiley the basic command "Beep" which helps already a bit, this works, but more elegant would be the balloon Tooltip of the icon in the notification area.

Comment: [How to Implement Tooltips for Status Bar Icons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/hh298404(v=vs.85).aspx) is the way to go, then. There will already be an instance of NOTIFYICONDATA that you'll want to modify (called `IconData` in this example, which you'll need to change to the actual name - probably `g_nid`); add only the `IconData.szInfo` and `IconData.uTimeout` fields, then invoke `Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_MODIFY, &IconData);` to pop up the notification.

Comment: Yes, I already have an instance of NOTIFYICONDATA called indeed g_nid. But it is maybe not as simple as that. I added szInfo and uTimeout after the initialisation of g_nid:

42 NOTIFYICONDATA g_nid={0};
43 g_nid.uTimeout   = 15000;
44 g_nid.szInfo = "Balloon ToolTip";

And now I get this error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.' in line 43
This error ist very much too unspecific for me.
I guess before realizing this I need to read a whole book about this and learn the basics. Here it is just some blind try and error for me, because my gaps in knowledge are too deep :(

Comment: Even when I try this very example with IconData, so when I add a new NOTIFYICONDATA, I get this error C2143 after NOTIFYICONDATA IconData = {0};
No worries, I did it successfully with Beep, this works and is enough for me. I think this is a bit hopeless because I am missing so much basics. Thank anyway. 
frank